# Sorting correctly data on DataSet Objet

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, winforms, dataset, oledb

using Windows forms with VB in Visual studio I have the next problem

when I initialize my object DataSet I got a different sort between tables

[Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jC9Xh.png)

I Have the next code:

```
oda = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select *From AccionesDeCorreccion", cadena)
ods.Tables.Add("AccionesDeCorreccion")
oda.Fill(ods.Tables("AccionesDeCorreccion"))
```

I try with the method sort in the next line

```
ods.Tables("AccionesDeCorreccion").DefaultView.Sort = "ID_ACCIONES_CORRECCION ASC"
```

but the table in my DataSet object doesn't change.

How can I sort the table on my DataSet in acendent order to have the same order of my DB in Access?

Comment: `DefaultView.Sort()` is applied to, well, the *View*. So the DataTable is *presented* sorted in a Control that shows its content. It doesn't affect the DataTable itself. If you want the DataTable's content sorted, you can do that with the query, or generate a new DataTable after, using, e.g., the `.AsEnumerable().OrderBy(...).CopyToDataTable()` extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    Dim dv As DataView = ds.Tables("AccionesDeCorreccion").DefaultView
    dv.Sort = "ID_ACCIONES_CORRECCION"
    Dim sortedDT As DataTable = dv.ToTable()
    sortedDT.TableName = "AccionesDeCorreccion"
    ds.Tables.Remove("AccionesDeCorreccion")
    ds.Tables.Add(sortedDT)
```

Or use LINQ to do it:

```
    Dim sortedDT As DataTable = ds.Tables("AccionesDeCorreccion").AsEnumerable().
        OrderBy(Function(x) x.Field(Of Integer)("ID_ACCIONES_CORRECCION")).
        CopyToDataTable()
    sortedDT.TableName = "AccionesDeCorreccion"
    ds.Tables.Remove("AccionesDeCorreccion")
    ds.Tables.Add(sortedDT)
```